# MySQLI Prepared statement won't insert into DB

Tags: php, mysqli

after I got advice to change my normal MySQLI query's to prepared statement, I've tried to change it all to prepared statement. The only thing is, is that my query then won't insert the info to the database.

I've tried to use var_dump to know if something is wrong, but var_dump gives me this back:

> Warning: var_dump() [function.var-dump]: Property access is not
>   allowed yet in /home/*******/domains/******.nl/public_html/contact.php
>   on line 123 object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL
>   ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["param_count"]=> NULL
>   ["field_count"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL
>   ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["id"]=> NULL }

My code:

```
            $stringMelding  = '<div class="attention closable"><strong>Helaas!</strong> Er is helaas een onbekende fout opgetreden met onze database, probeert u het later nog eens.</div>';
    $emailSent      = true;

//Controle spam.    
if($sDatum == $arrayInfoContact['datum'] && $sIPadres == $arrayInfoContact['ipadres'])
{
  $stringMelding = '<div class="warning closable"><strong>Helaas!</strong> U heeft in de afgelopen 24 uur al een bericht verzonden naar onze helpdesk!</div>';
}
else
{
  $stringMelding  = '<div class="success closable"><strong>Bedankt!</strong> Uw e-mail is verstuurd naar onze helpdesk, wij zullen zo snel mogelijk contact met u opnemen.</div>';

  //Prepared statement.
  $stmt  = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contact(naam, mailadres, bericht, ipadres, datum) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $sName, $sEmail, $sMessage, $sIPadres, $sDatum);

    $sName     = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['author']));
    $sEmail    = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
    $sMessage  = trim(nl2br($_POST['comment']));
    $sIPadres  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sDatum    = date('d-m-Y');

  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  //End of prepared statement.

  $mail           = mail($afMail, "Contact || RASolutions", $sBericht, $headers);
```

My query and whole system worked when I used MySQLI->query, so the query is working I guess, thank you for your help.

Comment: Are $sName, $sEmail, $sMessage, $sIpAdres, $sDatum defined in the current scope ?

Comment: Thank you Kei, I already had the variabels in the scope, but I noticed that $sIpAdres was misspelled, that was the "wrong" thing that didn't make my query work.

Comment: You define your variables AFTER the prepared statement?

Comment: you shouldn't use $mysqli->real_escape_string with prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines before connect

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

run your code again and see what errors it throw

Comment: This isn't a solution and will probably be deleted. Your ideas belong as a comment beneath the question.

Comment: Give man a fish - it will feed him for a day. Teach him how to fish - it will feed him for life.